# Qt Antialiasing with QPainter versus QStyleSheets

Tags: qt4, antialiasing, qpainter, qtstylesheets

Here are two `QWidget` painted black. The painting on left `QWidget` was performed using `QPainter` (overriding `::paintEvent(...)`). The right widget was "painted" using `QStyleSheet`.

[image]

This work was done in PyQt4 (`Python: 2.7.11+/Qt: 4.8.7/PyQt4: 4.11.4`). But you I have achieved the same result using PyQt5 and C++ Qt4/Qt5.

The code I used to paint the left `QWidget` is

```
def paintEvent( self, pEvent ) :

    painter = QPainter( self )
    painter.setRenderHints( QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing )

    painter.setPen( Qt.black )
    painter.setBrush( Qt.black )

    painter.drawRoundedRect( self.rect(), 10.0, 10.0 )

    painter.end()

    pEvent.accept()
```

The stylesheet used on the right widget is

```
setStyleSheet( "border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid black; background: black;" )
```

Why is there a difference between the two, especially the rounded part drawn by `QStyleSheet` far more smoother than the one done by `QPainter` despite using `QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing` render hint? You could use just `QPainter.Antialiasing` or `QPainter.TextAntialiasing` and still the situation does not improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a color to initialize the `QPen` you select a pen (and therefor a border) width of 0; my guess is that you should set it to 1 px as in the stylesheet to get the same result. Try

```
painter.setPen( QPen(Qt.black, 1) )
```

---

**Edit:** I just came about some old code of mine, implementing rounded borders for `QLabel`s. I was forced to correct the `QRect` for the pen width, else I got similarly ugly results. The implementation is placed in a custom style; the shadow color is set to the appropriate frame color:

```
void MyStyle::drawControlHeaderFrame(const QStyleOptionFrameV3* option,
    QPainter* painter, const QWidget* widget) const
{
    QPalette::ColorGroup cg = QPalette::Active;

    if(!(option->state & QStyle::State_Enabled))
        cg = QPalette::Disabled;
    else if(!(option->state & QStyle::State_Active))
        cg = QPalette::Inactive;

    const int lineWidth = 2, frameAdjustment = lineWidth / 2;
    QRect rect(option->rect);
    //Adjust for pen width
    rect.adjust(frameAdjustment, frameAdjustment, -frameAdjustment, -frameAdjustment);

    QPen pen(option->palette.color(cg, QPalette::Shadow));
    pen.setWidth(lineWidth);

    painter->save();
    {
        painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
        painter->setPen(pen);
        painter->drawRoundedRect(rect, 9, 9);
    }
    painter->restore();
}
```

Comment: Nope. I think the default width is 1. Nor does setting the with to anything else help. Tried width 0 and 2. Absolutely no change.

Comment: Actually, even this code you are suggesting gives the same result. Here is the screenshot of the implementation: http://i.imgur.com/ylK0YkH.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. When I draw without the border it looks fine, but with the border it looks bad. The [answer](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/65684-Qt-Antialiasing-with-QPainter-versus-QStyleSheets?p=289462#post289462) to your question in the Qt Forum did solve the problem. The border was being drawn outside the bounding rectangle of the control and was being cropped. By decreasing the width and height of my rectangle by 2x the pen width, giving space for the border on left+right and top+bottom, everything looked good again.